# JavaFX\UI кодер-дизайнер востребован в обществе Java?

Tags: java, gui, javafx, дизайн

До сих пор не могу понять, насколько JavaFX является востребованной технологией. Если мне лично нужна десктоп программа, то я выберу скорее всего JavaFX для создания ее интерфейса (сам раньше программировал на Java, увлекаюсь графическим дизайном; еще есть такая профессия UI designer). Вопрос: где я смогу применить знания по JavaFX и насколько JavaFX (UI) дизайнер востребован в обществе Java?

Comment: @almac, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

На данный момент сабж почти не востребован в виду большой сырости технологии и перепадов настроения его vendor'ов. Весьма высока вероятность, что о технологии стоит забыть.

Comment: На чем писать десктоп приложения - их gui вернее?

Comment: Swing, SWT.

Comment: Это же жуть как неудобно, особенно если дизайн сделан с нуля и нужное все прорисовывать отдельно (там на реализацию одного gui уйдет 30-50% времени разработки приложения)

Comment: Ну не так уж жутко неужобно. Особенно если использовать какой-нибудь SWIXML.

Comment: Apache Pivot?

Answer (score 0):

На JMonkey проекты посмотри, там же JavaFX сплошь и рядом:Р.
Я бы не сказал, что JavaFX очень сырой. Не всё, конечно, идеально, но пользоваться можно.
Меня больше волнует, как продумать архитектуру приложения, в котором все окна( их к примеру 3 или больше) независимы(не являются дочерними по отношению друг к другу). Тот MainController, что находится по дефолту в JavaFX 8, не подходит, потому как он ориентирован на работу с дочерними окнами, которых попросту нет ни в одном приложении(под дочерними окнами я подразумеваю Stage.initOwner() окна. В случае приложения с одним главным и несколькими дочерними окнами всё заметно упрощается). Как грамотно связать эти окна и управлять ими - непонятно.

Comment: Можно попробовать связать их через отдельный static class, или в отдельном классе нужные объекты как стати объявить, поставить на них ссылки и использовать из любого места, хоть откуда. У меня так логика в приложениях построена, вроде все работает и слава богу. :)